# scrollTop Outputting Rather Than Setting?

Tags: javascript, firefox, textarea, bookmarklet, scrolltop

I'm using some JavaScript from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4973, and the `scrollTop` suggestion below it, to create a bookmarklet for inserting a preset string of text into Blogger's new post `textarea`. The code looks like this:

```
//IE support
if (document.selection) {
    myField.focus();

    //in effect we are creating a text range with zero
    //length at the cursor location and replacing it
    //with myValue
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.text = myValue;

//Mozilla/Firefox/Netscape 7+ support
} else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {

    myField.focus();
    //Here we get the start and end points of the
    //selection. Then we create substrings up to the
    //start of the selection and from the end point
    //of the selection to the end of the field value.
    //Then we concatenate the first substring, myValue,
    //and the second substring to get the new value.
    var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
    var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
    myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
    myField.setSelectionRange(endPos+myValue.length, endPos+myValue.length);
} else {
    myField.value += myValue;
}
```

}

And the suggestion below that:

```
//add this to the start of function
textAreaScrollPosition = myField.scrollTop;

//add this to end of the function
myField.scrollTop = textAreaScrollPosition;
```

The `scrollTop` suggestion fails in Firefox, instead replacing the current page in the browser with the value of `textAreaScrollPosition`.

I added this to the front of the sandwiched down version for the bookmarklet:

```
javascript:var myField=document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox');var myValue='lol';
```

Altogether it reads:

```
javascript:var myField=document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox');
var myValue='lol';
var textAreaScrollPosition=myField.scrollTop;
if(document.selection){myField.focus();
sel=document.selection.createRange();
sel.text=myValue;
}else if(myField.selectionStart||myField.selectionStart=='0'){myField.focus();
var startPos=myField.selectionStart;
var endPos=myField.selectionEnd;
myField.value=myField.value.substring(0,startPos)+myValue+myField.value.substring(endPos,myField.value.length);
myField.setSelectionRange(endPos+myValue.length,endPos+myValue.length);
}else{myField.value+=myValue;
}myField.scrollTop=textAreaScrollPosition;
```

Without line breaks, though.

I am less than a JS wizard. I'm just trying to help a non-tech friend do something a little complex with Blogger. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** In addition to adding primitive page detection and replacing the preset text with a prompt box, I was able to solve the original problem by adding `myField.focus();` to the end:

```
javascript:if(document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox')){var myField=document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox');
var myValue=prompt('Insert text here.');
var textAreaScrollPosition=myField.scrollTop;
if(document.selection){myField.focus();
sel=document.selection.createRange();
sel.text=myValue;
}else if(myField.selectionStart||myField.selectionStart=='0'){myField.focus();
var startPos=myField.selectionStart;
var endPos=myField.selectionEnd;
myField.value=myField.value.substring(0,startPos)+myValue+myField.value.substring(endPos,myField.value.length);
myField.setSelectionRange(endPos+myValue.length,endPos+myValue.length);
}else{myField.value+=myValue;
}myField.scrollTop=textAreaScrollPosition;
myField.focus();
};
```

Not sure if that last semicolon is strictly necessary or not but oh well, solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the edited question, adding `myField.focus();` to the end solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may be making your bookmarklet too long to fit in a bookmark.  An option is to use a dynamic script tag:

```
javascript:document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).setAttribute('src','http://mysite/myscript.js')
```

Where myscript.js is the actual script that does the work.

If you keep it as a self-contained bookmarklet, be sure to surround the whole thing (after "javascript:") with curly braces.

Comment: One tip:  for development purposes, change the script url from "http://...whatever.js" to "http://...whatever.js?"+Math.random()  ....as that will make sure you always get the latest version of the file.  You'll find this makes bookmarklet development a lot easier, because you don't always have to be editing the bookmark itself, just edit a file on a web server.  If, when you are done you can compact the thing into a self-contained bookmark, cool, if not, stick with the hosted version.

Comment: Thanks, rob. I wasn't aware of that method till now. I tried testing for length by reducing the bookmarklet to this:... javascript:var myField=document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox');var textAreaScrollPosition=myField.scrollTop;myField.scrollTop=textAreaScrollPosition; ...Unfortunately, the same error occurs.

Comment: Edited my response above.  Lack of curly braces seem to be the problem...I think that is necessary if you declare variables in a bookmarklet.